# How can I change exception position?

Tags: python, exception, traceback, raise

I want to raise custom exception in my code, but unnecessary stack information shows.

Simple code:

```
def func1(val):
    if isinstance(val, int) is True:
        print('value:', val)
    else:
        raise TypeError('must be integer')

def func2():
    func1(1)
    func1('1')

func2()
```

Result:

```
value: 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/sss/etc/exceptionTest/exceptionTest.py", line 17, in <module>
    func2()
  File "c:/Users/sss/etc/exceptionTest/exceptionTest.py", line 14, in func2
    func1('1')
  File "c:/Users/sss/etc/exceptionTest/exceptionTest.py", line 9, in func1
    raise TypeError('must be integer')
TypeError: must be integer
```

The last stack is where `raise` code located, and it's not necessary. How can I remove that?

Comment: While you *can* remove the stack trace, the proper way to handle this is to catch the exception, handle it and print the part of the exception to want to show.

Answer (score 1):

You can set [`sys.tracebacklimit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.tracebacklimit) to `-1`:

```
import sys
sys.tracebacklimit = -1

def func1(val):
    if isinstance(val, int):
        print('value:', val)
    else:
        raise TypeError('must be integer')

def func2():
    func1(1)
    func1('1')

func2()
```

Output:

```
value: 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
** IDLE Internal Exception: 
TypeError: must be integer
```

Or if you still want to be able to see the source of the error, set `sys.tracebacklimit` to `3`:

```
value: 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/wil/Desktop/dsvcax.py", line 14, in <module>
    func2()
  File "C:/Users/wil/Desktop/dsvcax.py", line 12, in func2
    func1('1')
TypeError: must be integer
```

Note that `if isinstance(val, int) is True:` can be shortened to just `if isinstance(val, int):`.